# Nextpeer blank screen issue

Tags: ios, nextpeer

I am having problems with Nextpeer. I have added the right resourcebundle to the project and everything is working well except when pressing the play button on the dashboard Nextpeer only shows blank screen with pull handle on the bottom. Also, when the game ends there is no scoreboard shown, but scores are still saved if I look to the scoreboards.

When running the project on iPad everything works as supposed.

I hope somebody can help me.

Answer (score 0):

(Disclosure: I work at Nextpeer.)

Perhaps you added the iPad-only resource bundle? Make sure to use the NPResources_iPad_iPhone_Landscape.bundle or NPResources_iPad_iPhone_Portrait.bundle only (whatever fits your interface orientation). Also, it's a good idea to remove the app from the device/simulator, and make a clean build in Xcode (cmd+alt+shift+k), so the resources will be fully updated.

Finally, you're welcome to contact us directly at support@nextpeer.com.

Cheers!